# Best way to remove if statement inside view in asp.net MVC6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

Consider the following code:

```
@{
       if ((string) ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] == "Guest"){                                                                              
             <text>areaNav_link--selected</text>
       }
}
```

How would I go about removing that if statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use custom html helpers to remove logic.

As an example, you would call it as follows:

```
@Html.WelcomeText()
```

The logic could be moved into the helper as follows:

```
public static MvcHtmlString WelcomeText(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{
    var text = string.Empty;
    var areaName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["area"].ToString();

    if (areaName == "Guest")          
    { 
       text = "Hello Guest";
    }
    return new MvcHtmlString(text);
}
```

This way you could re-use it throughout the site with a single line of Razor code.

An alternative would be to create a [**TagHelper**](http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/views/tag-helpers/intro.html).

Comment: I am looking for something like this. However this doesn't seem to work. It only works if I change the method signature to: WelcomeText(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper).

But then I am receiving a runtime error of: KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Comment: I had to use htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["area"].ToString()

Comment: ViewContext.RouteData.Values["area"] not ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens.Values["area"]

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking about inline if statement then you can do something like that:

```
@((string) ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] == "Guest" ? "areaNav_link--selected" : string.Empty)
```

Comment: I was hoping to remove the logic from the view so that I could test easier?

Comment: Yes, you should always do that! But in that case I don't understand your question. Change the logic of your app so that you won't need if statements in your views. There are few options, for example you could fill property in the model and just use it on the view or couple of views.

Comment: I don't think that is possible? My application is split into multiple areas and this logic resides in my Master Layout?

Comment: There is always possibility to share your code between areas or multiple views. You could: put action to the base controller and call render action on the layout, your could render partial view or if you are using MVC 6 you can use ViewComponent feature.